# jQuery toggle and move to top

Tags: jquery

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('.start').click(function() {
            $('.startHere').fadeToggle("fast");
        });
    });
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $(".toggle").click(function() {
            $('.childtoggle').not($(this).find(".childtoggle")).hide(500);
            $(this).find(".childtoggle").slideToggle(500);
        });

        $(".childtoggle").click(function(event) {
            event.stopPropagation();
        });

        $(".gonext").click(function(e) {
            e.stopPropagation();
            if ($(this).parent().parent().next(".toggle").html() != undefined)
                $(this).parent().parent().next(".toggle").trigger("click");
            else
                $(".toggle").first().trigger("click");

        });
    });
</script>
```

That code does one simple thing. It lets me click on different divs, and then it closes and opens the next one. So I never have more than one div opened.

But what I'd like to do is simply make sure that every time I toggle a new div, the screen moves up to the divs top. Sometimes these divs have a higher height than the screen, and then the scroll is half way through the div.

Answer (score 0):

Try using https://api.jquery.com/scrollTop/ after click event.

something like this:

```
$('html, body').animate({scrollTop:$('#YOUR_DIV_ID').position().top}, 'slow');
```

Comment: @mezt  Could you post your html also? so that we could edit it.

Answer (score 0):

The `.slideToggle` method starts an animation that changes the height of the `<div>` so you can't set the scroll position until after it has finished. Try this:

```
function scrollToDiv() {
    $('#outerWrapper').scrollTop($(this).position().top);
}

$yourDiv.slideToggle(500, scrollToDiv);
```

Applied to your code (with some guesswork) this would be something like:

```
$('.toggle').click(function() {
    var $current = $(this).find('.childtoggle');

    $('.childtoggle').not($current).hide(500, function() {

        // After hiding the children show the current
        $current.slideToggle(500, function() {

            // After showing the current scroll to it
            $('body').scrollTop($current.position().top);
        });
    });
});
```

However that will take about a second to complete all the animations, which may feel a bit much to users. A better option may be to figure out the `position().top` of every collapsed `'.toggle'` after the page has loaded, and then use that cached value to scroll to.

Comment: Could you please make it after my example?

Comment: @mezt answer updated, but I've had to make some guesses about how the rest of your page works.

Comment: @mezt well I am guessing a lot about the rest of your page - what is the error that you're getting?